# scipy.sparse default value

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

The sparse matrix format (dok) assumes that values of keys not in the dictionary are equal to zero. Is there any way to make it use a default value other than zero?

Also, is there a way to calculate the log of a sparse matrix (akin to np.log in regular numpy matrix)

Comment: Not sure about the time this question was asked, but the default value should already be zero in recent versions of scipy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That feature is not built-in, but if you really need this, you should be able to write your own `dok_matrix` class, or subclass Scipy's one. The Scipy implementation is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/sparse/_dok.py). At least in the places where `dict.*` calls are made, the default value needs to be changed --- and maybe there are some other changes that need to be made.

However, I'd try to reformulate the problem so that this is not needed. If you for instance do linear algebra, you can isolate the constant term, and do instead

```
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
A = whatever_dok_matrix_minus_constant_term
def my_matvec(x):
    return A*x + constant_term * x.sum()
op = LinearOperator(A.shape, matvec=my_matvec)
```

To most linear algebra routines (e.g. iterative solvers), you can pass in `op` instead of `A`.

As to the matrix logarithm: logarithm of a sparse matrix (as in `scipy.linalg.logm`) is typically dense, so you should just convert the matrix to a dense one first, and then compute the logarithm as usual. As far as I see, using a sparse matrix would give no performance gain. If you need only to compute a product of a vector and the logarithm, `log(A) * v` vector, some Krylov method might help, though.

If you OTOH want to compute the logarithm elementwise, you can modify the `.data` attribute directly (available at least in COO, CSR, and CSC)

```
x = A.tocoo()
x.data = np.log(x.data)
A = x.todok()
```

This leaves the zero elements alone, but as above, this allows treating the constant part separately.

Comment: Thanks! It is kind of unfortunate that these simple functions are not implemented directly yet :(

Comment: I'd say that this would be a rather special rather than simple functionality for sparse matrices :)  I don't know if such things are implemented in other sparse matrix packages, but AFAIK Matlab doesn't seem to have such things. The problem is that many operations that you can do with sparse matrices (eg. factorization etc) wouldn't work well if the "missing" value was nonzero.

Comment: @pv Yes. I agree with you on default value issue. But other things like calculating log of matrix should have been implemented. A bit of a trivia. For certain types of sparse matrices X+1 works, but 1+X raises notimplemented exception :D