# "Sparse" matrix with nonzero default value in scipy

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, smoothing

I would like to create a "sparse" matrix where undefined entries aren't zero, but rather some value. The matrix I'm trying to create counts the outcome of certain kinds of interactions between elements i and j, but since there are far more entries than interactions it will necessarily be very sparse--however, it would be useful to enforce a uniform prior belief on the outcome of these interactions (i.e., Laplace smoothing), which would render the matrix necessarily dense, although still just as compressible. Thanks!

Comment: This is either unimplemented or only partially implemented in scipy. You can attempt to work around it by using the abstract linear operator interface if you are brave.

Comment: See the example in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4316 (to be included into a future scipy version, most likely 0.16)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the pointers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.sparse default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256206/scipy-sparse-default-value)