# Set default value to sparse scipy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there any way to set 1 as the default value for sparse matrix in scipy?

For example:

```
>>>M=scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((5,5), dtype=np.float, [default=1.])
>>>M.A
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Matrix sparsity is based on the 0 value, optimizations which are valid for the value 0, will not be valid for the value 1. If you wish the default value to be 1, you should use a normal matrix, and not sparse.

Comment: There is no such option as the sparsity of such a matrix would be 0. But maybe you can do something like this:  `M = np.full((5,5), 1, dtype=np.float)` and then  
    `M = sp.dok_matrix(M)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy.sparse default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256206/scipy-sparse-default-value)

Comment: Thanks, guys. But I think I'm going to have to implement my own sparse structure. I can not use dense matrix because of the memory limit.

Anyway, I just discovered that MeanShift of sklearn does not work with sparse matrix, so I'll have to implement the matrix and the algorithm. damm!

Comment: `pandas` sparse does allow for other fill values.  In fact `nan` may be the default fill.  For most calculations, `scipy.sparse` converts its matrices to `csr` format.  Recognizing that multiplication with 0s produces 0s is key to efficient sparse multiplication.

Comment: I have found a workaround using the default value in get method: M.get((i,j), default=1.)

Comment: This `get` works because `dok` is subclass of Python `dict`.  It won't work if the sparse matrix is transformed to another format for calculations (which `sklearn` is likely to do).  If this is all you need to do with the sparse matrix, it might simpler and/or faster to use a plain dictionary with tuple keys.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `np.ones((5,5))`:

```
M = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(np.ones((5,5)))
```

Comment: That doesn't set the 'default' value to 1, it just fills the whole thing with 1's.